# Getting messages feature in Debugbar to work in Laravel

Tags: laravel, debugging, message

I've installed Debugbar for Laravel as described in the steps on the website https://laravel-news.com/laravel-debugbar; and tried to make use of the Messages feature by placing the following below in my code.

```
Debugbar::info($object);
Debugbar::error('Error!');
Debugbar::warning('Watch out…');
Debugbar::addMessage('Another message', 'mylabel');
```

But when I run my website, I get the error message from Laravel saying:

```
1/1
FatalErrorException in HistoryController.php line 11:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Debugbar' not found
```

I have to go like /Debugbar::info(...) or put use Debugbar at the top of my code to not get the error message. Why can't I use it straight like Debugbar::info(...)?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to reference the facade without prefixing it with \ you should add

`use Barryvdh\Debugbar;`

to the top of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

after adding setting code in /config/app.php

you can use it as a facade

```
app('debugbar')->info('info message');
```

or

```
debugbar()->info('message');
```

no need `use`

Comment: I tried the other solutions on this page and none of them worked (at least in Laravel 8.x) but your solution works perfectly in Laravel 8.x, at least in my controller. Thank you!!! I'm still trying to figure out how to log messages in my Vue components so if you have any ideas, I'd be interested....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :

first you add below  code in `config/app.php`

in provider section

```
'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',
```

in aliases section

```
'Debugbar' => 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade',
```

after you should clear the cache like:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Hope this work for you !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Go to the terminal and install by typing:-

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
```

In second step, Check your laravel verision:-

```
php artisan --version
```

In third if your laravel version is greater than 5(Laravel 5.x)

add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php

```
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
```

add this to your facades in app.php:

```
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
```

Finally, published vendor configuration by command:-

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"
```

After vendor published clear cache,route,view by command

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan dump-autoload -o
```